# How to flatten state array in Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, state

I'm using Material-UI as a front-end for my e-commerce app.

I have an empty cart state array that will take 'stringified objects' that will later be parsed. Each handleChange() on the select component should add the an object (stringified object) onto the cart array.

The handleChange() nests the objects inside of itself ie [ob1,[obj2, [obj3, [etc[etc]]]]] --but i need [obj1, obj2, obj3, etc] instead...

Code --

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import soda from "./soda.jpg";
import * as firebase from 'firebase';



const useStyles = makeStyles(theme=>({
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345,
    marginTop: 170,
    marginLeft: 70,
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

export default function MediaCard() {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');
  let [cart, setCart]= React.useState([]);
  const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
    React.useEffect(() => {

      }, []);


 const handleChange = event =>{
           Array.prototype.flat(cart)
           setCart([cart].concat(event.target.value));
           console.log(cart);
         };



 let item = {
     itemDescription:"CBD FLOWER",
     itemName: "CBD",
     increments: {
         gram: {
             price: 10,
             weight: 1,
             name: "CBD",
         },
         eighth: {
             price: 30,
             weight: 3.5,
             name: "CBD",
         },
         quarter: {
             price: 70,
             weight: 7,
             name: "CBD",
         },
         half: {
             price: 140,
             weight: 14,
             name: "CBD",
         },
         ounce: {
             price: 300,
             weight: 28,
             name: "CBD",
         },

     }

 };



  let stringified = JSON.stringify(item.increments.gram);







  /*let getDiv = document.getElementById('testo');
      let getInput = getDiv.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for (let i = 0, n = getInput.length; i < n; i = i+1){
          console.log(getInput[i].value);
   }*/




  return (



    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          alt={item.itemName}
          height="500"
          image={soda}
          src={soda}
          title="CBD SODA"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {item.itemName}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            A refreshing drink filled w/ 28.8% CBD
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
      <div id="testo">
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo">Choose</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo"
          id="selectedItem"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          displayEmpty
          className={classes.selectEmpty}
        >
          <MenuItem value={JSON.stringify(item.increments.gram)}>10</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={JSON.stringify(item.increments.eighth)}>30</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={JSON.stringify(item.increments.quarter)}>90</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={JSON.stringify(item.increments.half)}>140</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={JSON.stringify(item.increments.ounce)}>300</MenuItem>
        </Select>
        <FormHelperText>Quantity + Price</FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
      <div id="seperator">
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary">
          Add To Cart
      </Button>
      </div>
      </div>

      </CardActions>


    </Card>


    );

}
```

I tried to flatten the array after but nothing. I also tried Array.prototype.push(), please help, lol

Comment: `Array#flat` is the way to go, but if you have to have cross browser support without any transpilers, go online and find a recursive array flatten function

Comment: I thought Array.prototype.flat() is supported in all browsers???

Comment: If it were released long enough ago, we could've named it `Array#flatten` without some outdated libraries robbing us of it ;). You can always look up compatability tables on mdn to confirm

Comment: @SonicStrains Give it a look: https://caniuse.com/#search=flat. If you're concerned about browser support, you could try [lodash.flattenDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flattenDeep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) what you need? The first parameter is the depth of flattening.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6, [7, 8, [9, 10]]]]];
var flatarr = arr.flat(Infinity);
console.log(flatarr);
```

Comment: Nice, I also noticed that you can chain the calls together like --setCart([cart].concat(event.target.value).flat(Infinity));

Comment: yes, or `setCart([...cart, ...event.target.value].flat(Infinity)); ` right?